# Parsing 3 digit input as TimeSpan

Tags: c#, parsing, timespan

User input is 555 I want it to be 05:55:00 (TimeSpan). How convert it to TimeSpan? What format use?

```
var a = TimeSpan.ParseExact(/*user input string*/"5:55", new string[] { "%h\\:mm" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);//OK output {05:55:00}
var b = TimeSpan.ParseExact(/*user input string*/"1111", new string[] { "%hmm" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);//OK output {11:11:00}
var c = TimeSpan.ParseExact(/*user input string*/"555", new string[] { "%hmm", "hmm", "hhmm"}, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);//Exception! None format works.
```

edit: In details I want to format user string intput to hours and minutes hh:mm. Eg user input string:

- "5" to be 05:00
- "12" to be 12:00
- "1111" to be 11:11
- "12:12" to be 12:12
- "4:44" to be 4:44
- and one not working "555" to be 5:55 (throws exception)

right now I'm using:

```
private static string[] _foramts = {"%hmm", "hmm", "hhmm","%h", "hh\\:mm", "%h\\:mm" };
return TimeSpan.ParseExact((string)value, _foramts, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("hh\\:mm");
```

with PadLeft, now there is no exception, but....

```
var d = TimeSpan.ParseExact(((string)value).PadLeft(4, '0'), new string[]  { "%hmm", "hmm", "hhmm", "%h", "hh\\:mm", "%h\\:mm" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("hh\\:mm");
```

"5" is now 00:05 and I want it to be 05:00

Comment: I think you will have to do it by hand either, get the input as `string` and do some *substring* or use it as `int` and do some `%` and `/` to get the digits you require.

Comment: It is already string. I just found solution, but not by format. Just make: `.PadLeft(4,'0')` with user string input.

Comment: This is really a bad method, but works : TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((60 * (int)(int.Parse(input)/100)) + (int.Parse(input) % 100));

Comment: Now that you change from seconds to minutes use TimeSpan.FromMinutes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `H` format matches one or two digits, based on number of digits available. In your case it will grab the first two digits "55" which are not a correct hour. Padding with zeroes is the way to fix that:

```
 var c = TimeSpan.ParseExact(value.PadLeft(4, '0'), new string[] { "%hmm", }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you want to handle different formats it would be easier to do plain-old if-elses that trying to match all possible inputs with one pattern.

```
public static TimeSpan Parse(string value) {

    if (value.Length == 1)
    {
        value = value.PadLeft(2, '0');
        value = value.PadRight(4, '0');
    }
    else if (value.Length == 2)
    {
        value = value.PadRight(4, '0');
    }
    else if(value.Length == 3)
    {
        value = value.PadLeft(4, '0');
    }

    return TimeSpan.ParseExact(value, new string[] { "%h\\:mm", "%hmm", "hmm", "hhmm" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);//Exception! None format works.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found solution, but not by format. Just make: `.PadLeft(4,'0')` with user string input. Still I'm curious does it can be done with format?

edit: but now this not work as expected:

```
var b = TimeSpan.ParseExact("5", new string[] { "%h" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

whit  `.PadLeft(4,'0')` it throws exception
:(

Comment: `var c = TimeSpan.ParseExact("5".PadLeft(4, '0'), "%hmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` will work.

Comment: Dodałem komentarz do głównego wątku. Po Twojej zmianie zamiast piątej godziny będę miał pięć po północy. :) I edited main question, after this change user intpu "5" will be five minutes after midnight not as expected 5:00 at morning